# FreeBSD console broken?

Tags: vim, console, freebsd, vi, .profile

It seems my FreeBSD console is misconfigured (i guess). I cannot use `home` or `end` buttons in command line (it prints `~`), and in `vi` left arrow is switching me from edit to command mode, which makes editing a little difficult. How can I know what's wrong and fix it?

I'm not a root, by the way, I just hope it's something with my profile or bash configuration.

Shell version: `GNU bash, version 4.0.35(0)-release (i386-portbld-freebsd8.0)`

**UPD**: fixed `home` and `end` keys in console by creating  `~/.inputrc` and pasting this:

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
# this is actually equivalent to "\C-?": delete-char
# VT
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
# kvt
"\e[H":beginning-of-line
"\e[F":end-of-line
# rxvt and konsole (i.e. the KDE-app...)
"\e[7~":beginning-of-line
"\e[8~":end-of-line
"\e[1;5C": forward-word     # Ctrl+right  => forward word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word    # Ctrl+left   => backward word
```

(solution from [here](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html))

Still, left arrow in vi bothers me, and I cannot install vim on the machine (maybe it's some vi quirk, idk).

Comment: Is this locally, or over ssh?

Comment: Over SSH. Client is NuSphere PHPEd embeded (though I may test with PuTTY).

Comment: No, PuTTY has the same problems. It must be server.

Comment: `vi` **does not support** arrow keys. When it was written, keyboards had arrows on HJKL keys.

Comment: Shouldn't vi use .inputrc stuff? I have another GNU/Linux box where arrows in vi work just fine.

Comment: @Kuroki: 1) No. `inputrc` is for readline, and `vi` uses ncurses.

Comment: @Kuroki: 2) That is most likely `vim` in "vi compatibility mode". (Try `:version` to check if it is.)

Comment: 2) Ha, you're right. `vi` is vim in compatibility mode and `vim` command is not found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by creating `.inputrc` file (see question update).

Answer (score 1):

You may find you can fix it all by doing something like:

```
TERM=xterm
```

...in your `.profile`.

Comment: I checked `set` and my TERM is already `xterm`.

Comment: Ah, if it's putty, then try the accepted answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161676/home-end-keys-in-zsh-dont-work-with-putty

Comment: I use different clients, not only PuTTY. Still, it seems I partially solved the problem.